# c++ parenthesis in front of member variable

Tags: c++

I am translating a c++ code to another language and am having difficulties understanding some code block in c++ code.[Here](https://github.com/BieremaBoyzProgramming/bbpPairings/blob/a8a4567f7a4ebf244dd3331b27eaa4b7851baf18/utility/dynamicuint.h#L666) is the line i am having trouble understanding the concept.

here is code snippet :

```
DynamicUint &operator=(const DynamicUintView<Iterator> that) &
      {
        view(*this) = that; // <== this line seems weird
        return *this;
      }
```

in `view(*this) = that;` what i've grasped is it is trying to initialize `view` member variable by `(*this)` value as parameter but as far as i saw there is no constructor taking one arguments in `DynamicUintView` class.could somebody shed some light on this?

Comment: how is vew defined? It looks like it returns a reference on something

Comment: @rhaport you can follow the link to see whole source code on github.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i can see something like this ` DynamicUint operator-() const &
      {
        return -DynamicUint{ *this };
      }` is it relevant?

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili No, nevermind. `view` is not a member *variable*, but a member typedef: `typedef DynamicUintView<iterator> view;`. Then yes, `DynamicUintView` must have a constructor callable with a single argument.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat could you please take a look at link i included in the question? i couldn't find such a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`view` is a type alias for `DynamicUintView<iterator>`](https://github.com/BieremaBoyzProgramming/bbpPairings/blob/a8a4567f7a4ebf244dd3331b27eaa4b7851baf18/utility/dynamicuint.h#L652), so this code does the following:

1. Constructs a temporary `DynamicUintView<iterator>` object by invoking the [implicit `DynamicUintView<iterator>` conversion operator](https://github.com/BieremaBoyzProgramming/bbpPairings/blob/a8a4567f7a4ebf244dd3331b27eaa4b7851baf18/utility/dynamicuint.h#L867), which in turn invokes the [two-arg constructor of `DynamicUintView<iterator>`](https://github.com/BieremaBoyzProgramming/bbpPairings/blob/a8a4567f7a4ebf244dd3331b27eaa4b7851baf18/utility/dynamicuint.h#L49).
2. [`view::operator=`](https://github.com/BieremaBoyzProgramming/bbpPairings/blob/a8a4567f7a4ebf244dd3331b27eaa4b7851baf18/utility/dynamicuint.h#L54) is invoked on this temporary object, passing `that` as the argument.

Comment: but as you may have noticed there is no constructor in  `DynamicUintView` class accepting one argument.could you please clarify this?

Comment: thanks for the answer. surprisingly vs-code c++ extension doesn't give any error in that line.but let me check if it really compiles.i'll let you know the result.

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili It should compile. I didn't notice the implicit conversion operator at first.